# Render Restforce::Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections

I am using the restforce gem and I have had success pulling the restforce collection and rendering the first user in the collection.

```
@users = client.query("select Id,Name from User where Id != ''")
# => #<Restforce::Collection >

@user = @users.first
```

I am stuck on what seems to be a pretty basic problem.  I cannot seem to create a view with a partial to iterate through the collection and show a list of all the users my query has returned.  See view below:

```
<ul class="users">
  <%= render 'user',  collection: @users %>
</ul>
```

See partial below:

```
<%= @user.Name %>
```

Not a lot going on here, just looking for a basic way to show a list of the user's names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate the collection.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <ul class="users">
    <li><%= user.Name %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

If you really need to, you can still use a partial like `<%= render 'user', user: user %>`

Comment: Thanks.  Any thoughts if I have a nested query like below:   @users = client.query("select Id,Name, (select email from Contacts) from User where Id != ''")
I can't seem to iterate through the nested collection.

Comment: What's the association between User and Contact that you want to explore? For instance, if I were to get all accounts and their contacts, I would have something like `client.query("select Id, Name, (select Email from Contacts) from Account")`. Then for each result in the collection, you could use `result.Name` for the account name and `result.Contacts` to get all the contacts for that resulted account.

Comment: The contacts actually associate with an account.  The query in your example is exactly what I have.  Then I produced the below in my view:  

<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <ul class="accounts">
    <li><%= account.Name %></li>
          <%= account.Contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <li><%= contact.Email %></li>
          <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

My issue is that I am receiving the below error:
"undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" This is in reference to the account.Contacts.each line

Comment: At least one of your accounts does not have contacts, so you check first contacts is present before starting looping.
If my answer is already suitable to your question, please accept it.